# infinite while loop although the statement becomes false

Tags: java, while-loop

This code give me infinite loop although sum become equals to 7 and become equals to (point)

```
while ( sum!=point || sum!=7)
{
    rollDices();
    System.out.println("rolling dices .. sum="+sum);
} //end while
```

but if I do this:

```
while(sum!=point)
```

or this

```
while(sum!=7)
```

it works fine without any problem

Comment: Both conditions must be false.

Comment: You probably want && instead of ||.

Comment: [Reading this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) will clarify why it happens and what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is slightly flawed. Your statement is saying while sum is not equal to point *or* sum is not equal to 7. It will always be not equal to one of them, unless they are the same.

I think you wanted to use `&&`:

```
while(sum!=point && sum!=7){
    rollDices();
    System.out.println("rolling dices .. sum="+sum);
}
```

With the `&&` once sum is equal to 7 or point it will exit the loop.

Answer (score 6):

If you're stuck and can't figure out why your `||` or `&&` isn't doing what you want it to do, work out a "truth table".

For `||`, the `OR` operator:

```
true || false  //returns true
true || true   //returns true
false || true  //returns true
false || false //returns false
```

And for `&&`, the `AND` operator:

```
true && true   //returns true
true && false  //returns false
false && true  //returns false
false && false //returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you wanted && instead of ||.  This makes it so that when sum becomes equal to 7 it will get out of the loop.

```
while( sum!=point && sum!=7){
    rollDices();
    System.out.println("rolling dices .. sum="+sum);
}//end while
```

So the only time it will stay in the loop is when sum isn't equal to point and sum isn't equal to 7.

Also a side note - Are you sure you want sum != 7?  Or is sum < 7 what you want in case sum became larger than 7?

Answer (score 1):

What happens to you is the following

the condition `sum != point || sum!=7` always returns true if point != 7.

so think point = 12 and you get on sum 6.

```
6 != 12 -> true
6 != 7 -> true
true || true -> true
```

lets imagine you get 7 on sum

```
7 != 12 -> true
7 != 7 -> false
true || false -> true
```